# Direct sum decomposition of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ using Fourier Transform

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Let $L_+^2(\mathbb{R})=\{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}):supp \hat{f}\subset\mathbb{R^+}\}$ and $L_-^2(\mathbb{R})=\{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}):supp \hat{f}\subset\mathbb{R^-}\}$, where $\hat{f}$ denotes the Fourier trans form of $f$ in $\mathbb{R}$. 
$\mathbb{R^+}$ and $\mathbb{R^-}$ respectively denotes set of positive and negative reals.
Then I need to show that $L^2(\mathbb{R})=L_+^2(\mathbb{R})\oplus L_- ^2(\mathbb{R})$.
I observed that $L_+^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $ L_- ^2(\mathbb{R})$ are orthogonal. Please help me to break   $f=f_1+f_2$ where $f_1\in L_+^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $f_2\in L_-^2(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: ok $support(\hat{f}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^+$. and the Fourier transform is a unitary operator $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and $L^2(\mathbb{R}) = L^2(\mathbb{R}^+) \bigoplus L^2(\mathbb{R}^-)$ because $L^2(\mathbb{R}) = L^2(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}),L^2(\mathbb{R}^+) = L^2(\mathbb{R}^+ \setminus \{0\})$

Comment: $support\hat(f)\subset\mathbb{R^+}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the fourier transform is an isometric isomorphism $\def\F{\mathscr F}\F \colon L^2(\def\R{\mathbf R}\R) \to L^2(\R)$. For a subset $A \subseteq \R$ let $\chi_A$ denote its characteristic function. Given $f \in L^2(\R)$, define 
$$ f_1 = \F^{-1}\bigl(\chi_{\R^+}\F f\bigr) $$
and
$$ f_2 = \F^{-1}\bigl(\chi_{\R^-}\F f\bigr) $$
As $\chi_{\R^+} + \chi_{\R^-} = 1$ almost everywhere we have $f = f_1 + f_2$.

Comment: +1 
thank you. I also did it same way, But I had a confusion, Because if $f_1\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$  then, $\mathscr{F}f_1=\chi_{\mathbb{R}^+}\mathscr{F}f$
should be continuous function. As characteristic function is not continuous, $\chi_{\mathbb{R}^+}\mathscr{F}f$ will not be continuous. that is unusual. please correct me if I am talking nonsense.

Comment: Note, that $\mathscr F f_1$ is continuous iff $\mathscr F f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $\mathscr F f(0) = 0$ ...

Comment: I can see that, so if $\mathscr{F}f$ is not continuous or $\mathscr{F}f(0)\neq 0 $ then $f_1\notin L^1(\mathbb{R})$